How to change parts of an (imported) rig from IK to FK?
I have this Fortnite character rig but it is IK. I wonder if I can switch only the arms to FK.
The FK bones are there, I just don't have any clues on how to do it.


Blend file:


Should be just removing the Inverse Kinematics constraint from the terminal bones, then deleting the control bones as they are then dead.

@TheLabCat Could you read the comments I left on josh sandelici's answer and help me with my question?

Select each forearm bone and turn down the Influence Slider on its IK Bone constraint.


It worked but the hands are weird, like they're still ik. How do I fix that?

I switched to edit mode, selected the hand bone, went back to pose mode and deleted the copy rotation constraint. Now the hand moves accordingly like in fk, but when I pose the character using the upper arm bone, the hand bone doesn't follow the movement. How do I fix that?
